# Meteor oplog for Mongo 2.6

Tags: mongodb, meteor

When I run lines from https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver I get

```
WARNING: The 'addUser' shell helper is DEPRECATED. Please use 'createUser' instead
2014-09-05T20:51:35.483-0400 Error: couldn't add user: "otherDBRoles" is not a valid argument to createUser at src/mongo/shell/db.js:1004
```

Because it was created for Mongo 2.4. Have someone managed to make it work on Mongo 2.6.1? 
If not, do I need to downgrade to 2.4? And if yes, how can I do it easily?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create your user this way, make sure you are authenticated and in the admin ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/use-database-commands/)) database:

1. Create the user `oplogger` ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/))

   ```
   db.createUser({ user: "<name>",
     pwd: "<cleartext password>",
     roles: []
   });
   ```
2. Create an oplogger role ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/createRole/))

   ```
   db.runCommand({ createRole: "oplogger", privileges: [   { resource: { db: 'local', collection: 'system.replset'}, actions: ['find']}, ], roles: [{role: 'find', db: 'local'}] })
   ```
3. Grant the role to the user ([docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/assign-role-to-user/))

   ```
   db.runCommand({ grantRolesToUser: 'oplogger', roles: ['oplogger']})
   ```
4. Use the MONGO_OPLOG_URL as an environment variable. Don't forget the `authSource=admin` parameter or it wont work. ([docs](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Oplog-Observe-Driver))

   ```
   MONGO_OPLOG_URL=mongodb://oplogger:<password>@server_ip/local?authSource=admin
   ```

There are also a few issues with 2.6 that aren't yet solved: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2121 & https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2278 though it is still very usable.

Comment: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Cannot grant nonexistent role find@local",
 "code" : 31
}

Comment: I made it work it seems, but when I add `MONGO_OPLOG_URL`, app doesn't launch

Comment: __From MongoDB 3.*__ you need to change `roles:[{role:'find'}...]` to `roles:[{role:'read'}]`, full string: `db.runCommand({ createRole: "oplogger", privileges: [{ resource: { db: 'local', collection: 'system.replset'}, actions: ['find']}], roles: [{role: 'read', db: 'local'}] })`