# Meteor.js - Can I use Mongodb version 2.6.5 for my production Meteor app? I need oplog tailing

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I saw a note somewhere to the effect that Meteor does not support oplog tailing in the newest version of Mongo.  What is the latest version of Mongo that I can safely use with Meteor if I want oplog tailing?

I need oplog tailing because I plan to write to my Meteor database from an external Python process.  I would like to use MongoDB 2.6.5 because it has support for bulk writes, which dramatically speeds up my system.

Also, if I do use Mongo 2.6.5 and oplog tailing is unavailable, will my database writes appear after the 10 second polling delay, which I think was the behavior before oplog tailing was introduced.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Officially MongoDB 2.6 isn't supported. It is possible to enable oplog tailing with Mongo 2.6 but the process is different given the new authentication system with Mongo 2.6

This is just a guideline, I'm not absolutely certain this will work for you, but it will give you a bit of direction. You need admin permissions to do this so ensure that you can with the user you're using to log in.

### Enable oplog tailing

Additionally you need a replica set. In the case of a single mongodb db you need a single set replica: (Better info on that here: https://gentlenode.com/journal/meteor-10-set-up-oplog-tailing-on-ubuntu/17)

### Create a user that Meteor can access

Here is where you may run into problems

1) First create a user `oplogger` (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/).

2) Create an `oplogger` role

```
db.runCommand({ createRole: "oplogger", privileges: [   { resource: {
    db: 'local', collection: 'system.replset'}, actions: ['find']}, ],
    roles: [{role: 'read', db: 'local'}] })
```

3) Grant this role to your user

```
db.runCommand({ grantRolesToUser: 'oplogger', roles: ['oplogger']})
```

Then you can use the `MONGO_OPLOG_URL` environment variable with `?authSource=local` at the end of the mongo url to enable oplog tailing on your meteor app.

Other helpful links:

- https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2036
- [Meteor oplog for Mongo 2.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25696140/meteor-oplog-for-mongo-2-6)

Again i'm not sure the commands will work exactly as they are. I remember doing this a couple of times but there was some tweaking required and mongo was quite stubborn when it came to granting the roles.

But all in all I've been using oplog tailing with Mongo 2.6/Meteor 1.0 without any issues so far.

Also, yes, if you insert a document directly into MongoDB there will be a max of a 10 second delay without oplog tailing.

Comment: I've used Mongo 2.6 for a while in a production environment with Meteor and so far we have had zero issues that were due to 2.6 instead of 2.4.